# Is there a javascript library that produces a vertically sliced background image like this? If not, how could I create it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slice, effect

I want a javascript library that vertically Slices the page a number of times and scrolls each slice at a different rate. The cool part is that the messy, discombobulated layers come together at a few predefined points to make everything look nice and organized. As you scroll further, the lower background image is sliced togheter with the top background image.

Here is an example of the animation in a website http://grouek.com

Is there a javascript library that i can use to produce this effect - what would be the ways i could creat this effect?

Comment: Reminder : Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know of any library that does that specifically, I'd imagine that a company like this custom built that website style, and did it with a team of highly experienced developers. And I don't think they would share it, because then their site wouldn't be unique.

I'm afraid you would have to write it yourself. And the question of how to do that is too broad of a subject to be asked in one question.